# Use Search-ADAccount to find all accounts with Account Expiration Date Not Set

Tags: powershell

Is there a way in Powershell to list all AD Accounts in the domain which don't have an account expiration date set? ie the accounts expiration date is set to 'Never'.

I can utilise Get-ADuser to get the expiry of a single account.

```
get-aduser username | Select-Object -Property name,Enabled,AccountExpirationDate,DistinguishedName | Where-Object {$_.AccountExpirationDate -eq '`n'}
```

However is there a way to use "Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring....." to get a list of all accounts in the domain which don't have an account expiration date set or a better way to do this?

When I use the below command I don't get any return information however I setup a test account with no Expiration Date (ie Never) set to test the command however the account is not displayed in the results.

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring | Select-Object -Property name,AccountExpirationDate | Where-Object {$_.AccountExpirationDate -eq '`n'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution combining Paxz reply above and this [Technet thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/07991630-4325-4311-a82a-fc9324bbf0dc/account-expiry-dates-or-account-never-expire-for-all-ad-users). The 'AccountExpirationDate' is too hard to filter out of AD effectively without exporting every users Account Expiration Date and formatting it to readable date-time string.

The Technet article linked above explains that "*accountExpires AD attribute is a large integer (64-bit) representing dates (in UTC) as the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since 12:00 am January 1, 1601. The AccountExpirationDate parameter is a property method that converts the value of accountExpires into the corresponding date in the local time zone*". From additional research when an account is set to Never expire it will have an 'accountexpires' integer of 9223372036854775807.

'Get-ADUser' can be used to filter for all accounts where the 'accountexpires' integer equals '9223372036854775807'. This avoids the need to convert the date for every account in the Domain.

```
Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq 'True' -and accountexpires -eq '9223372036854775807'} | Select-Object name,enabled,accountexpires,distinguishedName
```

Answer (score 2):

### Solution with Get-ADUser

You can still use `Get-ADUser` to find the accounts, if you use the correct Filter:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {-not(AccountExpirationDate -like "*") } -Properties AccountExpirationDate | Select-Object -Property name,Enabled,AccountExpirationDate,DistinguishedName
```

This will give you every Account where no value is set for the Attribute `AccountExpirationDate`.

---

### Solution with Search-ADAccount

If you still want to use `Search-ADAccount` you have to offer a timestamp until the Accounts should expire [(take a look at the ref)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/search-adaccount?view=win10-ps). There is no option to search for accounts that doesn't have any value set. You allways have to offer some kind of DateTime.

For example, if you want to find all Accounts that expire in 2 Weeks you have to options:

**First:**

A solution with a date on which the account expires:

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -DateTime ((Get-Date).AddDays(14))
```

**Second:**

A solution on the remaining days until the account expires:

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountExpiring -Timespan "14"
```